# In Excel, how do I get an unknown number of values from cells using a list from another cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet (Gantt chart) with dates in a column. Refer to the table below. The "Row" column is the row number in Excel, not a real column.

| Row | Depends on Row(s) (Col F) | Start (Col G) | End (Col H) | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **9** |  | 7/24/21 | 7/26/21 |  |
| **10** | 9 | 7/27/21 | 7/30/21 | Starts 1 day after row 9 ends. |
| **11** |  | 7/25/21 | 7/27/21 |  |
| **12** | 9,11 | 7/28/21 | 7/29/21 | Starts 1 day after MAX(row 9 end, row 11 end). |

How do I automatically set cells "Start10" and "Start12" to read from cell "DependsOnRows" in their row to get the max of any numbers in the "DependsOnRows" column using a formula or other method?

Currently, I'm using this formula in cells "Start10" and "Start12", which includes a manually typed "max" function:

Start10:
`=WORKDAY(MAX(H9), 1, Holidays!A$2:A$99)`

Start12:
`=WORKDAY(MAX(H9,H11), 1, Holidays!A$2:A$99)`

I want to automate the reading of the row numbers inside the max function so they are read from the "DependsOnRows" column.

I can use any format in the "DependsOnRows" column. I can use braces, brackets, commas, spaces, whatever. The list just ideally needs to be in 1 cell, not multiple.

Comment: A fun challenge, thanks for the question! For visibility, I would suggest altering your title to better reflect the crux of the question (getting multiple values based on directions from a single string) since getting the ```MAX``` of that set is something you already show how to do in the explanation of your problem (if that makes any sense at all).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `FILTERXML` function to change the string of row numbers into a dynamic array. From there, you can `INDEX` the position of each row along with a fixed column number (in this case 8, or column H) to get test values for the `MAX` function.

Something like the below works for me:

```
=WORKDAY(MAX(
INDEX($A$1:$I$13,
FILTERXML("<t><s>" &SUBSTITUTE($F13, ",", "</s><s>")&"</s></t>", "//s"),8)),
1, Holidays!A$2:A$99)
```

[image]

Comment: If I copy-paste your code into G13 in a test sheet like you made, and I remove the Holidays parameter (because I didn't make a Holidays sheet in the test workbook), I get a #NAME? value in the cell. It seems to be caused by the FILTERXML function based on tests where I copied portions of the formula into other cells, though I'm not 100% sure about that. I'm using Excel 2010. Could that be a limitation? Your typed code looks almost identical to your screenshotted code, so I don't think you made a typo.

Comment: Ah, the ```FILTERXML``` function is not supported in Excel 2010 so the formula won't work the way it would in Excel 365. Sorry about that, let me think of another option

Comment: Just FYI I have suggested adding the Excel-2010 tag to try and get you an answer that fits your situation